# Create index in sub document

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in mongoDB same like:

```
{
    "_id":"jery",
    "pets":{
        "rabbit":{
            "name":"momo",
            "age":2
        },
        "dog":{
            "name":"lizy",
            "age":2
        }
    }
}
```

This document structure is very easy to update/upsert,but difficulty to analysis.The problem is what should i do to create unique index on field `"name"`

Comment: Have you tried any thing? Can you show your effort?

Comment: yes,i do. i can't find any means to deal with this problem. if sub document is in an array,so i could create a  unique index for it.but the data struct is not array . and i search the mongoDB 3.2 document for solution. i thing i may try to use $text to find if i aready have same "name" in any documents. but "text index" it only create for a field with type "string"

Comment: Let me make sure what exactly your requirement is. If a `name` is there in one record, it should not come in any other record, irrespective of pets. This is what you want to do?

Comment: Right! that absolutely what i need.Are there any solutions?

Comment: You can not do unique index for your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Change your document structure as show below:-

```
{"_id":"jery","pets":[{"type":"rabbit","name":"momo","age":2},{"type":"dog","name":"lizy","age":2}]}
```

It will be easy to query then.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to do something like :-

```
db.collection.createIndex( {
   "pets.rabbit.name": 1,       
   "pets.dog.name": 1
} )
```

Comment: but rabbit and dog is dynamic inserting fields. that to say, i don't known what i already have like rabbit,dog or any pets else in this collection.whatever pets have a name with "name" when i insert pet with  same "name",collision happends.

Comment: is there any grammar to achieve  db.collection.find({"pet.$.name":"lizy"}).Count()